# Git Problem: gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: git, gitlab

why I cannot clone from GitHub repository in Ubuntu 20.04 lts. It shows the following error.
It says:

```
gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

I am working in a corporate proxy and I set my proxy as follows:

```sh
git config --global http.proxy  http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy:port
git config --global https.proxy  https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy:8080
```

I replaced proxy by my IP like: 172.90.7.4

My `.gitconfig` is configured as follows in the code:
[image: gitconfig]

Answer (score 1):

Try first:

```
https.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy:8080
              ^^^^
```

HTTPS connections should go through the same proxy, using *HTTP*, not https.

Comment: Hello dear VonC, Thank you for your immediate response.

Based on your advise, I configured it using the following command. But it still doesn't work.
 git config --global https.proxy  http://proxyusername:proxypass@192.90.7.4:8080
 
Now my configuration is:

user
 name = myname
 email = myemail@gmail.com
http
 proxy = http://proxyusername:proxypass@192.90.7.4:8080
 sslVerify = false
https
 proxy = http://proxyusername:proxypass@192.90.7.4:8080
 
 What may the case be please? My proxyusername and proxy password are correct.

Comment: @Abdurahman For testing, try and set the same proxy using `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, just to check if a `curl -L github.com` works (meaning if it display the source code the the GitHub front page)